# How do you navigate to safari extensions from App Store?

Tags: mac-appstore, safari-extensions

Not critical, but its bugging me.

I only know of one way to the safari extension gallery, ie, from the 'Extensions' tab in Safari's settings, <kbd>More Extensions...</kbd> button.

Is there anyway to navigate there directly in the App Store app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly enough if you open the App store app on your Mac and then type "Safari Extensions" in the search field, you will find a listing of all of the Safari extensions available from Apple on their app store.

I have never seen a built-in category for just Safari Extensions but this seems to work.

Comment: Yup, that seem like another way. Oddly Apple's apps and extensions are not very discoverable unless they're featured on in the top lists.